# How do I limit number of rows in the admin form in magento

Tags: forms, magento, magento-1.9

I have following code in my Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField('name', 'textarea', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'name',
));
```

I want to restrict the number of rows to display it like a single row, the code: `'rows' => 1` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use styling to do this

```
$fieldset->addField('name', 'textarea', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Name'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'name',
        'style'   => "height: 1em;",
));
```

Comment: In my case, changing 'textarea' to 'text' worked since I just needed 1 line, but your solution is better for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to change 'textarea' to 'text'